# How to get the row at a specific point in Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

In my [scrolling callback](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/callbacks#scrolling) I get a vertical scroll position and need the row which covers that position. Is there an API in tabulator to convert a scroll position to a row?

I tried the [`getRowFromPosition`](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/update#retrieve-position) function, however that expects an index in the overall row list, not a position in the tabulator window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `getRows` function passing in an argument of `visible`, this will return an array of [Row Components](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/components#component-row) for the currently visible rows.

If you are then looking for the top visible row you can get the first element in this array

```js
var topRow = table.getRows("visible")[0];
```

Comment: That's not a solution for my problem, as it only returns the top row in the visible area. What I'm after is to get the row at an arbitrary position, being currently visible or not.

Comment: If it is not visible it has no scroll position. Tabulator uses a virtual DOM, only the rows currently visible actually exist. anything outside the viewport of the table is created and destroyed as you scroll. the scroll bar is made to appear bigger than it is by a large amount of padding above and below the visible area, thus giving the illusion of a bigger table. This allows Tabulator to load 100,000's of rows without slowing down the browser with that many DOM elements

Comment: You mention in your question that you are looking to find the row at the top of the scroll position that you get from the scrolling events. That is exactly what the above code does if you call it in that callback, at the exact point you call that, the top visible row will be at that position in the scroll

Comment: I'm aware that these positions are rather virtual, and no, I'm not always looking for the top row, but might sometimes want to get the row under the mouse pointer.

Comment: You can get the row under the pointer using the `rowMouseOver` event, the event callback is passed the row component for the row the mouse is currently over